# No Careers invitations

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, invitation

On Careers Invitations page you say:

> Get to 150 completeness, and we’ll grant you a batch of invites.

I've got completeness rating of 162 for almost a week. In fact, I'm not going to invite everyone I know to Careers, I just wonder, where are these invitations? Should I meet some other criteria to get them?

Comment: Hi, we wait a week after original creation of the profile to avoid spamming you. That was the delay in this case.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. I think you should move this to answer.

Comment: I'd agree with the other commenters.  Because the description makes it sound automatic, it feels 'broken' that you sit there and grind up to get over 150, and then aren't rewarded instantly with invitations.  At the very least the verbiage should be changed to reflect this '1 week wait'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like invitations are awarded manually. Wait for some more time.

Comment: It seems you're right. I've got them an hour ago. Thanks

Comment: This should REALLY be added to the invitations page.

"Try out some of the features on your profile. Get to 150 completeness, and we’ll grant you a batch of invites." - it makes it sound automated when it's not, makes the feature look broken and just plain makes the site look bad.

Comment: I agree - I was about to ask about this same issue.  Thankfully I found this question and answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Me too (or rather me 3 at this point).

Comment: Come on, @FerretallicA - that's a bit rough...It is a nice, free service and  StackOverflow staff not promptly or automatically issuing invitations to us won't plain make the site look bad to any employers interested in hiring us. :-)

Comment: Come on, @Alastair - **that's** a bit rough. Everything else on **Stack Exchange** is so automated, it feels strange that this feature is both manual and lacks an explanation that it is manual. Sure it is free; and delays are reasonable for services that are deemed best to be manual; but an in-line explanation of same really seems appropriate.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens haha yeah it's definitely strange but it's not the enf of the world, in my opinion. For anyone sweating it, I have 3 spare invitations I can't see myself using anyime soon. :-P

Comment: @Alastair: Thank you for the offer; I Just started a 12 month contract, so hang on to them in case someone with greater need steps up. It just seems like a strange oversight for an organization that otherwise runs so smoothly.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it will remain a feasible option for very long as the site grows. Does anyone know on average how long it takes for invites to be rewarded?

Comment: The answer of invites come sometime in the future when we manually push the invite batch script took awhile to find here. Somebody should update the "invitation" page to mention it isn't automatic. I've got a friend who wants to sign up and finding out invites take an indeterminate time isn't very helpful after grinding out the 150+ completeness points.

Comment: I got my invites overnight so someone or something must be doing this more frequently.  Thanks.