# Careers invites when reaching 150 profile completeness

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No Careers invitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101222/no-careers-invitations)

When I click on invites in my careers menu, I see the following text:

> Try out some of the features on your profile. Get to 150 completeness,
>   and we’ll grant you a batch of invites.

I'm at 210 completeness, but didn't get invites. Did I misunderstand the text, or is there something wrong? Thanks :)

**EDIT**

My question was already answered here: [No Careers invitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101222/no-careers-invitations). Sorry for the inconvenience!